# Jsoup link selection

Tags: java, html, css, web, jsoup

I am trying to get all the links inside the `div class news column index` here is the structure of the html:

[image]

And here what I have tried but actually it doesnt give me any result, I dont really know why :///

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gsmarena.com/").get();
            Elements els = doc.select("#body > div > div.news-column-index > ul");
            for(Element e : els)
            {
                System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
            }
```

EDIT: this is the URL I am parsing: http://www.gsmarena.com/

Comment: Please add the URL to your questions, it will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
String str="http://www.gsmarena.com/"; Document doc=Jsoup.connect(str).userAgent(" Mozilla//5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit//537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome//49.0.2623.110 Safari//537.36").get();
Elements links = doc.select("li[class=news-column-list-item]");

for (Element link : links) {

    System.out.println(link.select("a[href]").attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: how did u get the doc, because I tried its not working for me :/

Comment: here is the connection `String str="http://www.gsmarena.com/";
  Document doc=Jsoup.connect(str).userAgent(" Mozilla//5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit//537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome//49.0.2623.110 Safari//537.36").get();`

Comment: now yes, it worked ! Thanks a lot, I think I had some problem in the connection thats why didnt worked from the first time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#body > div > div.news-column-index > ul > li >a
```

maybe you can try this selector
ul hasn't href attribute